# Create Custom View like ruler in Android

Tags: android

I have to create a ruler with 0-500 values on it.In which there would be fix needle on centre and ruler will be moving horizontally.

i have searched a lot and found some link

https://dhingrakimmi.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/android-measurment-scale-my-scale/?preview_id=2

using this i am able to draw scale but it is not scrolling it is just showing scale and centre needle.

please help me if any body have idea of that.

Answer (score -1):

I managed it using ListView and it is perfectly running.
I got the position in Onscrollchange listener